# Sync playlists from Linux to Android

Tags: linux, sync, android, playlists, galaxy-s3

I'm currently using OS X Mavericks on my Macbook Pro, but since it's an older model, I've been experiencing some slowdown since I upgraded.  After doing much research, I'm going to replace my current HD with another one and put [Elementary OS](http://elementaryos.org/) or [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/) on it.

I have [TuneSync](http://www.tunesync.com/) on both my computer and phone, which lets me select playlists on my GS3 from my iTunes and syncs them over WIFI without any hassle at all.

I'm wondering if there's a similar app which can do this in Linux.  Any suggestions would be great!

Thanks a bunch, and happy holidays :)

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't use Google Music with the Google Music Manager to keep your files sync'd?

Comment: I didn't know of that Google App until now.  Is there a limit to how much I can upload?

Comment: 20k tracks, 300MB each according to https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1143668?hl=en